# add values with one another with input field submit in php calculator

Tags: php, html

I want a calculator with my PHP code that adds values with one after one with submit button.like when I input a number then submit it and show it on the page then and input other, it should add previous number.and then enter another then submit.like these, numbers are adding with one another after submitting.

```html
<?php 
session_start();

?>

<?php
error_reporting(0);
?>
<html>
<title>adding input single values</title>
<body>

<form method="post"> 

    <input type="text"  name='number'  method="post"/>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
<?php
if(!isset($_POST['number']))
{

}
else
{  
$sum += $_POST['number'];
echo ++$sum;
    
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

[here is the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IF02F.jpg)

Comment: Please help in this regards.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use a session to store the previously entered number, when you post a variable do the math on the session variable so that way the next time the form is sent, it will add it, etc

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

if(!isset($_POST['number'])) {
    // ...
}
else {
    $_SESSION['number'] = isset($_SESSION['number']) ? $_SESSION['number'] : '';  
    $_SESSION['number'] += $_POST['number'];
    echo $_SESSION['number'];
}
```

Comment: it is not doing sum of the numbers. it is just arranging the number one after one.

Comment: I want to sum values one after one. please help.

Comment: @Alveena that's why I used dot instead of +

Answer (score 0):

You could use a hidden field instead of storing in the session.

```
    <input type="text"  name='number'  method="post"/>

    <?php
    if(!isset($_POST['number'])) {
        echo "<input type='hidden' name='prev_number' value=0 />"; 
    } else {  
        $sum = $_POST['number'] + $_POST['prev_number'];
        echo "<input type='hidden' name='prev_number' value=" . $sum . " />"; 
        echo $sum;

    }
    ?>
        <input type="submit" />
    </form>
```